# why use WeakReference on android Listeners?

Tags: android, weak-references

I am working on a large code base, and see in many places this type of code:

```
public static class RequestCustomData implements View.OnClickListener {
    WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivity;

    public RequestCustomData(MainActivity activity) {
        mainActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        MainActivity activity = mainActivity.get();
        activity.requestCustomData(true, null);
    }
}
```

I am a bit confused why this is used is so many places? I took a look at this document but it did not clarify well why this type of code is so heavily used on the app I am working on it

https://community.oracle.com/blogs/enicholas/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references

Anyone can explain me if this is a common pattern? If so, why?

Comment: Usually it's a band-aid for sloppy limits on the lifetime of a listener.  Note that in your example, if the intended purpose of the `WeakReference` ever did come into play, `onClick(...)` would throw a `NullPointerException`.  If this code isn't crashing, the use of `WeakReference` is probably an example of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> A weak reference, simply put, is a reference that isn't strong enough
> to force an object to remain in memory.

The authors of this code most likely wanted to avoid leaking of the Activity context if the `RequestCustomData` object could outlive the Activity itself.

I recommend [Romain Guy's post on this topic](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) as well as several specific cases to avoid:

- [inner classes and leaks](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html)
- [threads and leaks](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/activitys-threads-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: That is indeed the reason people do this.  But it's usually better to make sure the listener *doesn't* outlive the activity in the first place.

Comment: The link to Romain Guy's post shows _"Error establishing a database connection"_. The link is broken I guess

Comment: Romain Guy's post is unreachable. IMHO this article based on that post: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html